# Google Chrome Extension Store tester accounts-but how?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webstore

I uploaded the extension to the store, and added email address for tester accounts. I published the extension to the testers. Now what will happen? I thought Google would send them invitation mails but clearly this is not the case.

ALso, how many tester accounts can we add?

Comment: It took at least 30 minutes after I clicked publish before the URL worked. Prior to that, I was seeing the error "Item not found. This item may have been removed by its author."

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem (testers not being automatically notified) and found a solution/work-around:

1. Have each of your testers **Sign In** to https://chrome.google.com/webstore
2. Give them the *direct link* to your extension (i.e. [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/your-long-extension-ID-goes-here](http://#))

Info source:
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish?csw=1#publishing-to-test-accounts

Comment: This was very helpful, and seemed to solve the direct link not working for me.  You may also want to strip any query parameters (e.g. ?authUser=1) from your extension link if you have them.

Comment: But what if I remove someone from testers after they have installed the extension? The extension doesn't go away on its own. How do I remove it? Is there a way to check is someone is a tester.

Comment: It seems that the source link no longer includes the "publishing to test accounts" section. Also when I open my extension's page using the direct link I only see the latest version of the extension that was approved by Google, is there no way to see latest uploaded version?

Answer (score 7):

There is a button at the bottom of your app to "Publish to test accounts" It is all explained at the documentation which is Step 9

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish?csw=1#publishing-to-test-accounts

Comment: Still no solution!! When I go to the extension link with my tester account it says "Item not found. This item may have been removed by its author."

Comment: Well, in your dashboard, you don't see your testers?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

Comment: No Mohamed, I do not. I gave up on the web store now. Thanks

Comment: Strange, I see this: http://i.imgur.com/qs5pp.png  If you email the Chromium Extensions Mailing list, Googlers there can take an internal look. There must be a problem and they can figure it out quickly. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. I have published to a few tester accounts as documented and gave them a direct link to my extension. testers who are logged in to the store see `Item not found. This item may have been removed by its author.` I have just published to testers a minute ago, Could it be that it takes a few minutes/hours until it's visible to testers?

Comment: same thing for me, the testers get a 404 error when accessing the extension URL, while being logged in into the webstore dashboard.

Comment: Those of you that get **404 error - it takes about 60 minutes** till the tester can see the app after you add him.

Comment: The issue is lasting much longer than 60 minutes for me. It has been at least 3 hours.

Comment: Did they remove this option? I don't see it anymore, and the current guidance seems to be to publish a separate test version of the extension/app with "trusted publisher accounts". Very confusing experience.

Answer (score 3):

Just give it time to publish and tester can access with the direct link

Comment: Any indicator of how long it normally takes?

Comment: It took me like 1 hour.

Comment: Yes it took me around 60 minutes too ! I had to send the testers the direct link of the chrome extension.